# When one array is changed, another is changed. Unsure why

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a sudoku solver using a random sudoku board from an API. Essentially, I'm trying to have 2 boards saved in memory. One I display to the user, and the other to keep track of possible solutions and/or solutions for each cell.

The problem I'm running into is making the two arrays different. Not sure why, but whenever I update a cell in `boardState` in the `fillBoard()` function, it updates it for both `boardState` and `gameBoard`.

I've tried using the spread operator, tried looping through gameBoard and pushing each item into `boardState`, tried 1:1 mapping the two with `.map()`. Seemingly no matter which method I use to approach it, the console logs always output the same thing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let gameBoard = [];
let boardState = [];
getPuzzle();
document.querySelector('.genPuzzle').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    fillBoard();
})

//Fetch randomized Board
async function getPuzzle(){
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    gameBoard = [...data.board];
    boardState = gameBoard.map((x)=>x);
}

//Filling board with fetched Puzzle
function fillBoard(){
    for(let i = 0; i< 9; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j<9; j++){
            let currentCell = document.querySelector(`#cell${i}${j}`);
            let value = gameBoard[i][j];
            if(!value == 0){
                currentCell.classList.add('initialCell');
                currentCell.innerHTML = value;
            }else{
                boardState[i][j] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(gameBoard);
    console.log(boardState);
}
```

Comment: nested objects aren't cloned by spread, or slice, or map. You will need to explicitly clone each level that you don't want passed as references, so you could `boardState = gameBoard.map((x)=> [...x]);` for instance to clone the inner arrays of `gameBoard`

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: Additionally, sorting serialized info in the dom is usually a design flaw. Better to keep all your data in JS space and simply render the DOM one time upon update so data flows in one direction and you have separation of concerns, decoupling UI and logic. Should be faster too, if that matters.